# RuntimeError: GnuPG is not installed. using windows machine and python 3.10

Tags: python

I am on windows and need to decrypt a file using python-gnupg library. Tried everything, pip install python-gnupg, added executable to system env, added exe to vscode specific env, uninstalled and then installed all libraries, gave home directory to this command: gpg = gnupg.GPG(<home dir where gpg binary is installed>). nothing seems to work. seems like the library is broken. is there any solution to this?

I am on windows and need to decrypt a file using python-gnupg library. Tried everything, pip install python-gnupg, added executable to system env, added exe to vscode specific env, uninstalled and then installed all libraries, gave home directory to this command: gpg = gnupg.GPG(<home dir where gpg binary is installed>). nothing seems to work. seems like the library is broken. is there any solution to this? please let me know

Comment: In general, I don't recommend using that library at all, _and I say that as one of its contributors_. The primary maintainer is a fine person who does good work, but by virtue of what it (a wrapper around a very old project with a complicated codebase and a long history of compatibility-breaking changes) is it's almost impossible for python-gnupg not to be a huge mess. Myself, I dropped it entirely in favor of using Go and [`x/crypto/openpgp`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp).

Comment: That said, it _does_ work if you get all the details right (that means, among other things, having the right gnupg version for your specific python-gnupg release installed; having the PATH include the directory with that executable; etc). For us to know _which_ details are wrong, though, you need to include a [mre] with your question and _precise details_ on the errors (either use `verbose=True` or the `logging` module to turn logging all the way up, and include the logs in the question).